# How can I make a control enabled even when a modal form is shown?

Tags: c#, winforms, modal-dialog

In a WinForms app, I have a specific set of buttons inside a UserControl which I need to be intact always, even if a modal form is currently displayed.

I do not have control over the modal form appearing (can't change ShowDialog to simply Show). I wonder if there is any way to override/suppress the modality of another form.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It looks like you don't want to show a Modal dialog then. You can use Show(this), disable everything in the Form that creates the owned Form except the UserControl. Subscribe to the Form.FormClosed event to re-enabled what was disabled. The use of container controls (panels and such) can ease the procedure.

Comment: @Jimi I edited the question. I cannot control the modal form itself.

Comment: What do you mean you don't have control over this dialog? Where does it come from? You'll have to provide a much more explicit description of your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to go is creating your own modal-form that will look like or share the same functionality as the uncontrolled modal form (I'm doing that a lot with message boxes for example)

Once you will do that, you will be able to call the modal form with 'Show()', and on the caller form, you will be able to determine what happen when your custom modal form will be shown (disable all controls instead of the user control that hosting the buttons you want to keep clickable).

If you cannot create your own modal-form as suggested, maybe you should consider invoking the user control and the uncontrolled modal with different executables (one can invoke the other) so it will work in parallel side by side on the screen. You can share the information between the two assemblies using named pipes for example.